# How to set multiple cookies in one page using php

Tags: php, cookies

I want to show two forms with cookies if first time user landing on page show form no. 1 and second time landing show form no.2 if third time no form show plzz help me

Comment: Please see: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172496). What may be confusing you is that [Stack Overflow is not like all those other sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128554/172496)

Comment: Be clear about your question. Explain it in detail.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you need two cookies for that. You can just use one cookie and call it something like "visits".

```
if ( !isset( $_COOKIE['visits'] ) ) {
    $_COOKIE['visits'] = 0;

    // display form no. 1
} elseif ( $_COOKIE['visits'] == 1 ) {
    // form no. 2
} else {
    // no form
}

$_COOKIE['visits'] ++;
```

Comment: This doesn't set a cookie, just reassigns the current global COOKIE. use setcookie